# How do I redirect from a subdirectory on an Apache server to the dynamic web root / domain root?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, document-root

On an Apache server, I want to redirect any requests made to certain subdirectories to the web root. For example, if a user tries to go to `http://www.my-domain.com/js/`, I want to redirect them to `http://www.my-domain.com/`. I'm assuming I need to use an `.htaccess` file and `mod_rewrite` to do this, but maybe there's a better way.

More specifically, I want to redirect a user anytime they make a request to a directory that does not contain an index file. The trick though is that I do not want to hard-code the domain URL to redirect to. Instead, I want to use a variable for the web root / domain root so that regardless of which environment I use the code in, it will work.

How do I do this? Thank you.

---

Adding to my question a bit, I tried both of the following in an `.htaccess` file, but neither worked.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ %{HTTP_HOST} [L]
</IfModule>
```

The above gave me some sort of weird Apache error and didn't redirect.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} [L]
</IfModule>
```

This redirected to the root directory page, but didn't change the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer to my own question. The following works:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ / [L,R]
</IfModule>
```